# Regular Expressions. Reversal of concatenated strings verification

Tags: formal-languages

What is the significance of reversing string $v$ in the following? Can't the string $v$ contain exactly what is in the string $v^R$, since you are just choosing from the alphabet $\Sigma^*$? I don't fully comprehend this question.

> Consider the language
>   $$L = \{uabcv\mid u,v\in\Sigma^*\}$$
>   over the alphabet $\Sigma = \{a,b,c\}$.  Is it true that reversal of $L$ is the set
>   $$L_2 = \{ucba(v^R)\mid u,v\in\Sigma^*\}\,?$$
>   (Please note that the parentheses are used only to clarify that it is only the string $v$ that is reversed.)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please don't put multiple questions in the same post unless they're very closely related. I deleted your first question, since you'd already answered it yourself, leaving nothing for us to do except check your working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part,
$$L=\{aw|w\in\{a,b\}^*\}$$
and
$$L_R=\{wa|w\in\{a,b\}^*\}$$

It is true that $L_R$ is the reverse of $L$. $L$ represents the set of strings starting with the symbol $a$, and $L_R$ represents the set of strings ending with the symbol $a$. Note that for some $w$ such that $aw\in L$, you only need to find some $w'$ such that the reverse of $aw$ is $w'a$. You do not need $w=w'$, so your example does not counter the statement.

For every string $w\in\Sigma^*$, where $\Sigma=\{a,b\}$, reversing the characters of $w$ must also belong to$\Sigma^*$. Thus, every string $aw$ in $L$, there is a string which is its reverse in $L_R$ and vice-versa.

For the second part, there is no significance in reversing $v$. It might be intentionally a part of the problem statement.

Comment: So for the second part, the v(R) is likely introduced for unnecessary ambiguity?  Is it then true, exactly the same way that the first question was true. That is, L= ALL strings containing abc, whereas L(R)= ALL string containing cba?

Comment: Also, Did you mean {a,b}* in your second paragraph? @GoodDeeds

Comment: For the first comment, most likely yes. For the second, no $\Sigma$ is the alphabet, which is $\{a,b\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Any string $s\in L$ has this form:
$$
s = \underbrace{x_1\dotsm x_n}_ua\,b\,c\,\underbrace{y_1\dotsm y_m}_v
$$
where $x_i, y_j\in \Sigma$. Its reversal, then, will be
$$
s^R = \underbrace{y_m\dotsm y_1}c\,b\,a\underbrace{x_n\dotsm x_1}
$$
Since you need this to be of the form $p\,c\,b\,a\,q^R$ (where I used different variables to lessen any possible confusion), it will suffice to have
$$\begin{align}
p&=y_m\dotsm y_1 = v^R\\
q^R&=x_n\dotsm x_1= u^R
\end{align}$$